# Remove Runnable queue

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, handler

The function `showSnackBarInfo()` is run several times in lambda when the `startTimer` method is called:

```
private var timer: CountDownTimer? = null
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
private val timerAction = Runnable { showSnackBarInfo() }
var timerDuration = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)


fun showSnackBarInfo() {
    Log.d("some", "showSnackBarInfo")
}

fun startTimer() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(timerAction)
    handler.postDelayed(timerAction, timerDuration)
}

fun cancelTimer() = handler.removeCallbacks(timerAction)
```

Comment: From where are you calling it?

Comment: @vilpe89 from my activity

Comment: Are you sure you are calling it only once, please post the calling code

Comment: @mightyWOZ i called two times, but in 2 different cases.
https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/4e1a2f6cf2b06c8c46b348b9106c1a2d

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with TimerTask:

```
private var timerDuration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)
private var timer: Timer? = null

fun showSnackBarInfo() {
    viewContract.showInfoMessage()
}

fun startTimer() {
    timer?.cancel()
    timer = Timer().apply {
        schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                showSnackBarInfo()
            }
        }, timerDuration)
    }
}

fun cancelTimer() {
    timer?.cancel()
    timer?.purge()
    timer = null
}
```